# How to connect LSTM with Dense?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, keras-layer

When trying to connect LSTM with Dense, it gives an error (when trying to train):

```
input = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1], None))
X = Embedding(num_words, max_article_len)(input)
X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout = 0.5)(X)
X = LSTM(128)(X)
X = Dense(32, activation='softmax')(X)

model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[X])
...
>>> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense to have shape (32,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I tried different connection options, but the error repeats:

```
X, h, c = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, return_state=True, dropout = 0.5)(X)
X = Dense(32, activation='softmax')(X)
>>> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense to have shape (32,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Any solution options on the functional API / Sequential?

Data conversion code:

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
articles = train['text']
y_train = train['lang']

num_words = 50000
max_article_len = 20

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=num_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(articles)

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(articles)
x_train = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_article_len, padding='post')

x_train.shape
>>> (18974, 100)
y_train.shape
>>> (18974,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter must be set to `False`;

```
X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout = 0.5)(X)
X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False)(X)
```

If you still have issues, then the problem must be with your input shape.

Comment: Then I encounter an error


>>> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (18974, 1)

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer since I led you unintentionally on a bad path; indeed, the return_sequences must be false on the last LSTM layer; however, there must be something wrong with the input shape in this case.

Comment: I rechecked the input and I think that it is correct. I supplemented my question and showed how I prepared the data. I had a regular table with two columns: lang and text

Comment: Oh I forgot to_categorical for y_train. Now everything works. Thanks for help

Comment: No issue. Please, if you may, also upvote the answer since it solved your problem. Thank you